# Do Gamecube games on the Wii use the Wii's system clock?

Tags: nintendo-wii, nintendo-gamecube

I have recently got a Wii, partly to play Gamecube games (on disc), and I was just wondering where games that use the system clock get their date and time. Do they use the system clock for the Wii, or is there a separate setting for the Gamecube.

So far, I haven't played any games that use the system clock, this is more out of curiosity.

Comment: Why would there be a separate GC clock that's not synchronised with the normal one, with no way to set it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they use Wii's system clock so games like animal crossing will work in real time in your Wii just like in gamecube.

Answer (score -2):

Thankfully no they don't do this. This is because you are using the GameCube disc in the Wii.